# How About onActivityResult when I want to read multiple file from storage

Tags: image, storage

**How About onActivityResult when I want to read multiple file form storage**

In this xml form I have to take multiple image file  by clicking  different different button from the app external storage but their is a difficulties on ActivityResult override method calling , because it call automatically and can't be call multiple time for for different different button

It's working fine for single file picking and get image URI.

So how can I fix the ActivityResult override method for different different button in a single activity

public class Application_Form extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ActivityApplicationBinding binding;

boolean isOnlyImageAllowed = true;
private static final int PICK_PHOTO = 1958;
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityApplicationBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    setContentView(view);
  

    //check user storage permission

    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }




    binding.form4.choosePropertyFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent;
            if (isOnlyImageAllowed) {
                // only image can be selected
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            } else {
                // any type of files including image can be selected
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("file/*");
            }
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PHOTO);
        }
    });



}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_PHOTO) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        binding.form4.selectedPropertyFile.setText("" + imageUri.getLastPathSegment());

    }

}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Taking a array to pick photo then check with if else statement by array index**

public class Application_Form extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ActivityApplicationBinding binding;

boolean isOnlyImageAllowed = true;
private static int[] PICK_PHOTO={0,1,2,3,4,5} ;
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityApplicationBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    setContentView(view);
    binding.appBar.title.setText("লাইসেন্সের জন্য আবেদন করুন");
    binding.appBar.back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onBackPressed();
        }
    });


    //check user storage permission

    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }


   

    binding.form4.choosePropertyFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent;
            if (isOnlyImageAllowed) {
                // only image can be selected
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            } else {
                // any type of files including image can be selected
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("file/*");
            }
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });


    binding.form4.chooseBankCertificate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent;
            if (isOnlyImageAllowed) {
                // only image can be selected
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            } else {
                // any type of files including image can be selected
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("file/*");
            }
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });



}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_PHOTO[0]) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        binding.form4.selectedPropertyFile.setText("" + imageUri.getLastPathSegment());

    }
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_PHOTO[1]) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        binding.form4.selectedBankCertificate.setText("" + imageUri.getLastPathSegment());

    }

}
```

}